# how to pass dropdown selected value to another dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

when i click button  dropdown selected value pass to anotherone dropdown ..

Dropdown Selected value First one:

```
      <fieldset class="form-group">
           label class="form-label" for="exampleInputEmail1">Location <em style="color:red;font-size:18px;">*</em></label>
          <select class="select2-arrow" id="txtLocationID" name="txtLocationID"><option value="">--- Select Location ---</option>
    <option value="1">EGL 4 club house</option>
    </select>
   </fieldset>
```

In above dropdown selected value passed to second one dropdown

```
 <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label" for="exampleInputEmail1">Location <em style="color:red;font-size:18px;">*</em></label>
   @Html.DropDownList("txtLocationID", null, "--- Select Location ---", new { @class = "select2-arrow" })
  </fieldset>
```

Button click: EGL 4 club house Value pass to second dropdown

```
$("#VenueBooking").click(function (e) {

        var locationID = jQuery('[id$=LocationID]').val();

    });
```

Comment: You want to show only selected value of first dropdown or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var locationID = jQuery('[id$=LocationID]').val();
jQuery('[id$=txtLocationID]').val(locationID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply set select value to next dropdown with `val()`

```
$("#VenueBooking").click(function (e) {
   $('[id$=txtLocationID]').val($('[id$=LocationID]').val());
});
```

Comment: @IvinRaj you can do `#txtLocationID` in place of  `[id$=txtLocationID]`. I think razor templating will not append value to `id`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not getting what exactly do you want to achieve but as far as I've understood, do you want to select one value in one dropdown and want to select that value in second dropdown?
You could achieve it in JQuery by doing this approach:

```
$("#firstdropdown").change(function (e) {
$("#seconddropdown").val($("#firstdropdown").val());

});
```